# Usage of 'stripslashes()'

Tags: php

I'm getting backslashes when I insert a record into the database and i would like to know where to put the stripslashes function to take care of them.

Here is what binds them.

```
$st->bindValue( ":content", $this->content, PDO::PARAM_STR );
```

And here is another function that stores all parameters and parses and stores the date so i figure it might be able to do the same for the string.

```
public function storeFormValues ( $params ) {

    // Store all the parameters
    $this->__construct( $params );

    // Parse and store the publication date
    if ( isset($params['publicationDate']) ) {
        $publicationDate = explode ( '-', $params['publicationDate'] );

        if ( count($publicationDate) == 3 ) {
            list ( $y, $m, $d ) = $publicationDate;
            $this->publicationDate = mktime ( 0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y );
        }
    }
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
       $content = stripslashes($content);
    }
}
```

I cannot turn magic quotes off in the php.ini because I'm using yahoo web hosting (not my choice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn off magic quote gpc without editing php.ini . You can turn it off using following code.

```
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
?>
```

Source: [php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)